# servlet to jsp pass value

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to simple pass value servlet to jsp page. I want to run jsp file and onload data is display from getting servlet

But I got null : `"Servlet communicated message to JSP: null "`

below is my code.

**java code**

```
package api;

public class ServletToJSP extends HttpServlet {
      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //communicating a simple String message.
        String message = "Example source code of Servlet to JSP communication.";
        request.setAttribute("message", message);

        RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("javaPapers.jsp");
        reqDispatcher.forward(request,response);


      }
}
```

**jsp file**

```
<%@ page import="api.ServletToJSP" language="java" %>


<html>
<body>
<%
  String message = (String) request.getAttribute("message");
  out.println("Servlet communicated message to JSP: "+ message);

 // Vector vecObj = (Vector) request.getAttribute("vecBean");
//  out.println("Servlet to JSP communication of an object: "+vecObj.get(0));
%>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>ServletToJSP</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>api.ServletToJSP</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>

      <servlet-name>ServletToJSP</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/ServletToJSP/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Avoid using scriptlets but instead use the [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)

Comment: Post web.xml code here. and how you are calling servlet ?

Comment: Along with JSTL there is an expression language that allows access to values so your message would be accessed as ${message} in the jsp without the requirment of the rest of the scriptlet code. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Comment: What is your welcome file? How your servlet is invoked?

Answer (score 3):

There are few things to change:

**In servlet**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //communicating a simple String message.
    String message = "Example source code of Servlet to JSP communication.";
    request.setAttribute("message", message);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("javaPapers.jsp").forward(request,response);
}
```

**In jsp**

```
<html>
  <body>
    Servlet communicated message to JSP: ${message}
  </body>
</html>
```

*Changes made:*

- In servlet, used request.getRequestDispatcher(String url)
- In jsp, removed servlet import.
- In jsp, used EL to get attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("javaPapers.jsp");
```

with

```
RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("javaPapers.jsp");
```

Comment: ServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(uri) only accept absolute path to the context root,so must start with a '/'.so, the code can change to getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/javaPapers.jsp");

Answer (score 0):

Passing the param using the `request.setAttribute("message", message);` should work using this code:

```
RequestDispatcher  rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("yourPage.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

You can also pass the attribute using the URL in dispatcher :

```
RequestDispatcher  rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("yourPage.jsp?message=some message");
    rd.forward(request,response);
```

Also you can share info using session object.

```
session.setAttribute("message","your message");
```

And then retrieve it in jsp using:

```
String message=(String)session.getAttribute("message");
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use context path to get message from servlet to jsp. This will definitely work I have done it.

```
String msg = "Message from servlet to jsp";
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(contextPath+"/report/test.jsp?msg="+msg));
```